# datepicker is not a function em typescript

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, typescript, data, datepicker

Quero implementar o datepicker em um projeto com typescript.

Tentei usar inicialmente instalar o datepicker pelo npm mas não consegui...então estou tentando da forma padrão mesmo.

Inicialmente importei

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Depois na construção da minha classe inicial inicializei a varivel do input data como um datepicker

```
this._inputData = $('#data').datetimepicker();
```

E então recebo a mensagem

```
NegociacaoController.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function
at new NegociacaoController (NegociacaoController.js:6)
at app.js:1
```